# Drop Hive Table If Exists Error by Spark

Tags: mysql, hive, apache-spark

I have Hive, MySQL and Spark. MySQL is Hive metastore_db. I follow this guide to configurate it (http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/4.2.0/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_18_4.html). It is ok for me to do drop table command under hive shell environment. But when I enter into spark-shell env, I use `hiveContext.hql("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS hivetesting")`. And then, I get following error:

```
ERROR Hive: NoSuchObjectException(message:default.hivetesting table not found)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$get_table_result$get_table_resultStandardScheme.read(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:27129)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$get_table_result$get_table_resultStandardScheme.read(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:27097)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$get_table_result.read(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:27028)
at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:78)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.recv_get_table(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:936)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.get_table(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:922)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.getTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:854)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.invoke(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:89)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.getTable(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getTable(Hive.java:950)
......
```

Every command is running successfully under `hive shell`. Meanwhile, `show tables` `create table src(id string)` and `select count(*) from src` are ok under `spark-shell` by hiveContext. **Except drop table if the table not exists.** Drop table can be run successfully when the table exists.

What can I do to get this resolved?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Check the parm `hive.exec.drop.ignorenonexistent`. Is it's `false`, then set it to `true` and try again

Comment: I check hive-site.xml and find that this attribute's value already is set to true. Here is :<property>
  <name>hive.exec.drop.ignorenonexistent</name>
  <value>true</value>
  <description>
    Do not report an error if DROP TABLE/VIEW specifies a non-existent table/view
  </description>
</property>  The problem is still there.

Answer (score 2):

This problem doesn't exist in Spark 1.5.1; I'm able to successfully call

```
hiveContext.sql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_table')
```

Spark is a rapidly evolving platform, and things change between versions.